# Reference individual field of model in another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have three models so far:

```
class clientCode(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.unique_id

class clientAccount(models.Model):
    clientCode = models.ForeignKey(ClientCode, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='clientBusiness',null=True)
    clientAccount = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=False)
    clientName = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False)

class assets(models.Model):
    assetName = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False)
    assetCurrency = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False)
    assetCode = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.assetName
```

Now, I would like to have a model containing ALL the fields from the above + an amount and transaction.

I started as so...

```
class Holdings(models.Model):
    holdingsName = models.ManyToManyField(assets)
```

The issue is this, while this returns the assetName which is what I'd like, how do I retrieve the assetCurrency?

I guess I need to know: How do I reference an individual field from one model another model?

I am truly lost on how to do this, i've tried various ForeignKey, ManytoMany.. Is the correct approach to build a form that includes all the fields and posts to said model?

**To clarify, I would essentially like clientAccount and assets to remain as lists, and the Holdings model fields to be dropdowns relating to these models?**

Sorry if this is unclear and thanks in advance for any help! - I'm sure Ive got the wrong end of the stick on how to build the models.

Comment: This post may be of interest to you:
https://godjango.com/blog/django-abstract-base-class-multi-table-inheritance/

Comment: Hi @vasia, Thanks for your fast response. I have tried using the inheritance method, however,  I would essentially like clientAccount and assets to remain as lists, and the Holdings model fields to be dropdowns relating to these models. Could you provide any help with that? Starting to think the only way would be to inherit the model and build a form to retrieve the drop downs?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you need to first of all determine how are your models related to each other or what are the relationships between ClientCode, ClientAccount, Assets and Holdings.

As an example, loosely defined holdings are stocks, property or other finanical assets in someone's possesion. So your models for holdings and assets could be something like that.

Also please follow the Django Naming Conventions for your code. I have changed field/model names to reflect that below. Link [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style)

```
class Asset(models.Model)
   asset_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False)
   asset_currency = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False)
   asset_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.asset_name

class Holding(models.Model)
    holding_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    assets = models.ManyToManyField(Asset, related_name='holdings',
                                              through='HoldingAsset')# if you want some more explicit fields on the through model

    def __str__(self):
       assets = self.assets.all()
       asset_currencies = [asset.asset_currency for asset in assets]
       return '%s -- %s' % (self.holding_name, self.asset_currencies)
```

Now if you get a holding object like this (ignoring any unhandled errors here)

```
holding = models.Holding.objects.get(holding_name='Test_Holdings')
```

to access your assets and their currencies , you could do something like this.

```
assets = holding.assets.all()
asset_currencies = [asset.asset_currency for asset in assets]
```

To load holdings based on assets, or vice-versa, you will need to use modelforms and use a chained drop-down approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Angela. Following on from your suggestion, if I was to try and also add a ManytoManyField into the Holding model relating to the asset_currency. How do I write the def __str__(self): so that it will popuate this field with whats already in the asset model?

Comment: you cant add a manytomany for asset_currency as asset_currency is the property of the asset model. Relationships are defined between models not between model fields. You can access all model-fields once you have a relationship defined, using the `__` double underscore. I have edited my answer to include the def __str__(self) method.